# $\frac{A}{B}$ as the sum of distinct inverse naturals.

Tags: number-theory, egyptian-fractions

Is there a method to taking some rational number and expressing it as the sum of distinct inverses of the natural numbers?  For example, $$\frac{2}{3} = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{1}{2}$$ and $$\frac{47}{60} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5}$$.  If there is some way to go in reverse, does it work for every rational number, and is it the only way?

Comment: Google egyptian fractions. There is always a way to find a representation , if we assume that the given number is larger than $0$ and smaller than $1$. Just take the largest fraction of the form $\frac{1}{n}$ smaller than the current number and subtract it until you arrive at $0$.

Comment: The representation is not at all unique.

Comment: Interesting results applying that algorithm to 121/173, for instance.

Comment: Perhaps the OP meant distinct inverses of natural numbers, so $1 = \frac{1}{1}$ and $1 = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} +\frac{1}{6}$ are acceptable, but $1=\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2}$ is not.

Comment: Yes, Malcolm is right.

Comment: @JohnBarber Tricky. The best I can get (in terms of minimal number of terms and minimal denominators) for 121/173 using a version of David Eppstein's [Small Numerator Reverse Greedy algorithm](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/numth/egypt/greed.html) is $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{14} + \frac{1}{346} + \frac{1}{9688}$

Comment: @PM2Ring I wrote a little Mathematica script to apply the algorithm described by Peter above, and I find that for 121/173, it results in the denominators 2, 6, 31, 2012, 4624439, 29939605866171, 1493966665702738318997802564.

Comment: @JohnBarber Yes, the greedy algorithm often blows up like that. OTOH, no single known algorithm always gives the best result, which is part of the charm of Egyptian fractions. :) And of course there isn't a simple definition of best: we want small denominators, but we also want to minimize the number of terms.